# Intuition about non-existence of non-integrable functions.

Tags: integration, intuition

Recently in the class of integration our teacher told us that some functions like $e^{x^2}$ are non integrable , so it is not possible to obtain a function which is it's anti-derivative. But we know that integration is area under the curve so for a smooth function like $e^{x^2}$ I have an intuitive feeling that the graph of area under the curve be another smooth curve. Also every curve on the graph represents a function so isn't  there a contradiction ?

Comment: There's two points to be made. First, nonintegrable functions do exist, but they are not what your teacher described. Those functions have antiderivatives which are nonelementary, which is not the same thing as being nonintegrable.

Comment: It's not integrable in the sense that you can't express its antiderivative in terms of non-elementary functions. You can still find the area of it, but you're pretty much limited to approximating it (outside of very special cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in terminology.  The function $e^{-x^2}$ is definitely integrable.  It's just that the expression for the integral, $I(x) =  \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2} dt$ cannot be written in terms of elementary functions.  The fix is that Mathematicians simply give the function, $I$ its own name, in this case, the error function.

An example of a function that is non-integrable near zero is $I(x) = \int_{-1}^{x} \frac{dx}{x}$.  This function can only be integrated for values of $x$ less than zero.

Comment: OK I got your point , so it means that the antiderivative is definitely a smooth graph but as for now we can't express that graph in basic algebraic form.

Comment: @Abhinav that's exactly right.